# flex items are not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have given a fixed width to the `ul` and want the `li` to flow down when `ul` reaches the max-width.

My HTML - here `List 3 and List 4` should flow down. That is start from right under `List 1 and List 2`

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fh9ue6q5/)

```css
.dropdown-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.open>ul {
  display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Drop it
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:50px">
    <li>
      <a href="#">List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">List 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">List 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">List 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo, add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the flex container.

The default value is `nowrap`.

[**Revised Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fh9ue6q5/4/)

From MDN:

> [***flex-wrap***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)
>
> The CSS `flex-wrap` property specifies whether flex items are forced
>   into a single line or can be wrapped onto multiple lines.
>
> **Initial value:** `nowrap`
>
> **Applies to:**   flex containers

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why you're using inline-flex, but changing your .open>ul to display: inline-block; yields the result I think you're looking for. Hope I was able to help!